# Manipulate JSON data into another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to figure out how to manipulate my JSON data and create a separated object with the manipulated data.

To be more precise, I am using this JSON file: https://jsonblob.com/57a70ca4e4b0dc55a4eb1f73

I am trying to convert [dataset][data] into this format:

```
[Date.UTC(2013,5,2),0.7695],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,3),0.7648],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,4),0.7645],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,5),0.7638],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,6),0.7549]
```

So I need to use the fields `[dataset][data][i][0]` *(Date)* and `[dataset][data][i][4]` *(Value)* and somehow put it in a new JSON formatted object but I have no idea how to do it.

Someone can help me with this situation?

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('json/AAPL.json', function (data) {
        // Data manipulation into a new object??
    });
});
```

Comment: let us know what you have tried that didn't work

Comment: when `data` is your object converted from json you could make a copy of the object and than change its properties.

Comment: @Alexander, I understand the logic but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: @DulyKinsky Didn't tried anything yet because I have no idea where to start.

Comment: @AndreiRăileanu after checking the json file i now get where you are going. First thing. Do you want to have the data sub-object in a own object ? Second thing. You could loop through the created object from 1st and then push the data from every run into a new array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('json/AAPL.json', function (data) {
        var correctFormat = data.dataset.data.map(function(item) {
            return [new Date(item[0]), item[4]];
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is just map one :

You have an array of elements (arrays themselves) and you want to keep and modify just first and fifth element of each sub-array

So you can do it like this

```
var data = [
  [
    "2016-08-02",
    106.05,
    106.07,
    104,
    104.48,
    32731069,
    0,
    1,
    106.05,
    106.07,
    104,
    104.48,
    32731069
  ],
  [
    "2016-08-01",
    104.41,
    106.15,
    104.41,
    106.05,
    37141424,
    0,
    1,
    104.41,
    106.15,
    104.41,
    106.05,
    37141424
  ],
  [
    "2016-07-29",
    104.19,
    104.55,
    103.68,
    104.19,
    27076805,
    0,
    1,
    104.19,
    104.55,
    103.68,
    104.19,
    27076805
  ]
  ];
var  result = data.map(x => [Date(x[0]), x[4]]);
console.log(result); // [ [ 'Sun Aug 07 2016 14:29:22 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))',104.48 ],
                     // [ 'Sun Aug 07 2016 14:29:22 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))',106.05 ],
                     // [ 'Sun Aug 07 2016 14:29:22 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))',104.19 ] ]
```